# Calling a script (some language) from a Swift app at Runtime

Tags: python, ios, swift

I want to write an app that has the ability to call a script of some language from an IOS app at runtime.  From what I have found so far this is not possible unless I do something like embedding Python in the app.

Basically I want to have the ability to add an object with some properties and functions to a database online. The user will then be able to download the object to their IOS device and the object and its functionality will be added to the app.  There might be hundreds of these scripts available so hard-coding them in Swift seems impractical.

Comment: not an answer, but I'd be very weary of this execution model as a massive attack surface for arbitrary code execution exploits.

Comment: Apple won't let you side load executable code anyway, unless your app is educational (like Pythonista). All those who have tried have been rejected, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Apple does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious, but you can probably run scripts as JS and catch the result from them - like put your JS to some endpoint and execute it.

But for your purpose I can't think about this solution as a good idea.